# Improving BLEU score of custom model

Tags: microsoft-translator

I currently barely have 10,000 training sentences and I'd like to improve the BLEU score of the model. Is there a way to get more sentences, or get around the 10,000 minimum?

If not, how do I improve the score with the 10,000 sentences I have?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of 10k is required for training to complete.  You could add any source of data in your desired language pair, but you really want to find training sentences that are relevant to what you will be translating.